# NPE: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

[image: mensaje de error: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference]

He estado revisando ese código pero no sé como solucionarlo, no sé que cosa poner o como hacerlo para que ya no salga ese error

Comment: Si quieres  mapear dos tipos de datos tendrías que instanciar `fUser` como setUid para  comparar los datos.

Comment: Hola Sebastián, cuando plantees preguntas sobre código y mensajes de error es mejor que agregues el texto del código y el texto del mensaje de error. Es mucho más fácil de leer y analizar que una imagen, la cual en algunos dispositivos se ve con dificultad. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para cambiar la imagen por el texto. Gracias.

Comment: osea como sería en realidad?

Comment: está bien lo haré

Comment: posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387688/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-reference

Answer (score 0):

el error que tienes es que modelUser.getUid() te está devolviendo null y por lo tanto cuando llamas al método .equals te lanza este error.

Para que no salga el error, puedes modificar el if así:

```
    if(modelUser.getUid()!=null&&!modelUser.getUid().equals(fUser.getUid()))
```

ten en cuenta que tanto modelUser como fUser tampoco deberían ser nulos.