# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, excepciones, nullpointerexception

estoy intentando crear una app de notas,  y por el momento no estaba teniendo ningún inconveniente, ya la había terminado en su momento, pero le quise agregar una funcionalidad para eliminar una nota. Lo pude hacer sin problemas eliminando directamente la nota desde el listener OnItemLongClick, e invocando el mismo método removeNote que aparece a continuación en el código, con la diferencia de haber pasado un int como parámetro en lugar de una Note. Pero al ser muy "peligroso" esto de eliminar una nota con solo mantener el dedo apretado, quise hacerlo mediante un nuevo diálogo, que es el que me lanza esa excepción. Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NoteAdapter mNoteAdapter;
    private ListView listNote;

    private Animation mAnimFlash, mAnimFadeIn;

    private boolean mSound;
    private int mAnimationOptions;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    int mIdBeep = -1;
    SoundPool mSoundPool;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNoteAdapter = new NoteAdapter();
        listNote = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        
        listNote.setAdapter(mNoteAdapter);

        listNote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (mSound) {
                    mSoundPool.play(mIdBeep, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }

                //recuperamos la nota de la posición pulsada por el usuario
                Note tempNote = mNoteAdapter.getItem(position);

                //creamos una instancia del ShowNote
                DialogShowNote dialogShowNote = new DialogShowNote();

                dialogShowNote.SendNoteSelected(tempNote);

                dialogShowNote.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

            }
        });

        listNote.setLongClickable(true);

        listNote.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Note noteToDelete = mNoteAdapter.getItem(position);


                DialogDeleteNote dialogDeleteNote = new DialogDeleteNote();

                dialogDeleteNote.ReceiveNoteSelected(noteToDelete);

                dialogDeleteNote.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");


                return false;
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                                                .build();

            mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                        .setMaxStreams(5)
                        .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                        .build();

        } else {
            mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("fx2.ogg");
            mIdBeep = mSoundPool.load(fileDescriptor, 0);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //el método onResume se llama tanto después del onCreate como cuando volvemos a la actividad despues de un stop
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("To Do List", MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSound = mPreferences.getBoolean("sonido", true);
        mAnimationOptions = mPreferences.getInt("animacion", Settings_Activity.FAST); //al haberla puesto como estática, podemos acceder a ella para
                                                                                            // establecer el valor por defecto
        mAnimFlash = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.flash);
        mAnimFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadein);

        if (mAnimationOptions == Settings_Activity.FAST){
            mAnimFlash.setDuration(100);
        } else if (mAnimationOptions == Settings_Activity.SLOW){
            mAnimFlash.setDuration(1000);
        }

        mNoteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

   public void DeleteNote(Note n) {

       mNoteAdapter.removeNote(n);

   }

    public void CreateNewNote(Note newNote){

        //este método recibirá (mediante el parámetro) una nueva nota creada por el diálogo

        mNoteAdapter.addNote(newNote);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){

            //debemos invocar una nueva instancia del diálogo para mostrar notas
            DialogNewNote dialogNewNote = new DialogNewNote();

            dialogNewNote.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "note_create");

        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings_Activity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mNoteAdapter.saveNotes();
    }

    public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<Note> myListNote = new ArrayList<>();

        //utilizaremos la clase JSONSerializer que creamos con anterioridad
        private JSONSerializer mSerializer;

        public NoteAdapter(){

            //creamos el objeto JSONSerializer (mSerializer), y le pasamos los parámetros fileName y Context
            mSerializer = new JSONSerializer("MyNotes.json", MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());

            //realizamos la carga de las notas guardadas en el fichero, con el método Load creado en el JSONSerializer
            //al poder arrojar excepciones (IOException y JSONException, lo rodeamos de un try catch
            try {
                myListNote = mSerializer.Load();

            } catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //guardamos las notas creadas en un fichero, con el método Save creado en el JSONSerializer
        public void saveNotes(){

            //al poder arrojar excepciones (IOException y JSONException, lo rodeamos de un try catch

            try {
                mSerializer.Save(myListNote);

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myListNote.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Note getItem(int position) {
            return myListNote.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //en este método vamos a programar la lógica de las celdas de la lista

            //la vista no ha sido accedida anteriormente, por lo que hay que inflarla a partir del layout
            if (convertView == null){

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            //cuando estamos aquí ya tenemos la lista bien definida
            //cargamos todos los widgets y layouts

            TextView tv_title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            TextView tv_description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            ImageView iv_important = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_important);
            ImageView iv_todo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_todo);
            ImageView iv_idea = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_idea);

            //y podemos proceder a ocultar las imágenes que sobran del layout
            // y rellenar el título y descripción de la tarea

            Note currentNote = myListNote.get(position);

            if (currentNote.isImportant() && mAnimationOptions != Settings_Activity.NONE){
                convertView.setAnimation(mAnimFlash);
            } else {
                convertView.setAnimation(mAnimFadeIn);
            }

            if (!currentNote.isImportant()){

                iv_important.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } if (!currentNote.isIdea()){

                iv_idea.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } if (!currentNote.isToDo()){

                iv_todo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            tv_title.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
            tv_description.setText(currentNote.getDescription());

            return convertView;
        }

        public void addNote(Note note){

            myListNote.add(note);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public void removeNote(Note note){
            myListNote.remove(note);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }

}
```

**DialogDeleteNote**

```
public class DialogDeleteNote extends DialogFragment {

    private Note mNote = new Note();

    public void ReceiveNoteSelected(Note receivedNote){
        this.mNote = receivedNote;
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_note, null);

        Button btn_cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bt_cancelar);
        Button btn_si = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bt_si);

        builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Eliminar nota");


        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        btn_si.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

                mainActivity.DeleteNote(mNote);

                dismiss();
            }
        });


        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
2020-09-05 20:31:36.439 16581-16581/com.eddd.misnotas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eddd.misnotas, PID: 16581
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.eddd.misnotas.MainActivity$NoteAdapter.removeNote(com.eddd.misnotas.Note)' on a null object reference
        at com.eddd.misnotas.MainActivity.DeleteNote(MainActivity.java:148)
        at com.eddd.misnotas.DialogDeleteNote$2.onClick(DialogDeleteNote.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: El error es claro, la referencia de la variable `mNoteAdapter` es `null` en el contexto que la estás usando. Esto quizá esté provocado porque dicha variable es instanciada dentro del `onCreate()` del `MainActivity` y como usas una instancia de `MainActivity` creada manualmente por tí, dicho método `onCreate()` no es invocado nunca y por ende no se instancia el `NoteAdapter`.

Comment: No puedes crear una instancia de un Activity como si fuera una clase. Haces `MainActivity activity = new Activity();` y aún así es una referencia a un objeto diferente. Lo que puedes hacer es crear una interface en el diálogo, implementar esa interface en el MainActivity y pasarle la referencia al Diálogo e invocarla. Puedes buscar tutoriales de como comunicar eventos entre Activities, Dialogos y Fragmentos, hay muchísimas formas.